# Creating a survey containing categories wss 3.0

Tags: wss-3.0, survey-list, categories

Friends. I have a simple WSS 3.0 installation where I need to create a survey which must contain some categories grouping together questions. Could I use some sharepoint feature for this?   I thought that the branches in surveys could help me achieve this, but it doesn't seem so. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you mean by grouping. You might do just as well with a custom list with forms which are smartened up with some script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We just want to create some subtitles preceding certain number of questions, sort of a logical grouping of related questions.

Comment: If it's just some sort of headings in the page, you could definitely do it with some script. Here's one way to do it from Jim Bob Howard: https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/jquery-to-the-rescue-labeled-sections-on-default-forms.aspx